# How to know the all minimum privileges that software needs?

Tags: proxy, firewall, vps, privileges

I am using a VPS as a public proxy, and I have begun to realize that I must make my VPS more secure as I have seen in [Securing Public Shadowsocks Server](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks/wiki/Securing-Public-Shadowsocks-Server). [Shadowsocks](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks) is a fast tunnel proxy that helps you bypass firewalls.

As described in these [Shadowsocks documents](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks/wiki/Securing-Public-Shadowsocks-Server), I created a user named `ssuser`, but it failed to run `Shadowsocks` under `ssuser` because of `Permission denied: '/var/run/shadowsocks.pid'`. Then I have to return to root and give `ssuser` privilege to control `/var/run/`. But is it safe if I give the whole folder privilege to `ssuser`? I don't know. After I did that, it said: `Permission denied: '/var/log/shadowsocks.log'`.I have to do such things over and over.

Everyone doesn't know the details of a new application at first, maybe you can execute it successfully for now, but it would be broken after some time because of the lack of some specific privileges.

Is there a quick and easy way to find out all the minimum privileges that software needs?